# should I trigger the same function as DLQ for a SNS triggered Lamda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which is triggered by a SNS. I read that I could handle error if lambda fails even after retrying with SQS in the dlq. What will be best way to go about it.

I can have a SQS as DLQ and then trigger a different lambda function or I can have a SNS to trigger the same function.

If I use the same one that triggered the lambda then I can use the same logic that failed for retry else I will have to write code to handle the error with SQS as the DLQ.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a bad practice.

DLQ is what's used to put all messages for which the function failed for.

I don't think you'd want to keep running the failed function on the same input. This applies to most relevant use-cases. Of course one could find an extreme use case that you'd want to keep trying forever.

Plus, DLQ is a queue. The name you'll supply should be a name of a queue (SQS), not a topic (SNS).

Comment: DLQ can be both queue and sns in latest lamda for nodejs